# Spark Api GET/POST request data using Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, http-post, get-request

How do I write a script that retrieves a listing by ID and saves it to a file as JSON: http://sparkplatform.com/docs/api_services/listings

How do I write a script that creates a new contact record, and then prints the new contact’s record (standard output is fine): http://sparkplatform.com/docs/api_services/contacts

SPARK_API Gem github page to answer the questions:
https://github.com/sparkapi/spark_api (provides auto parser)

**CODE**

```
SparkApi.client.get  "/listings/#{listing_id}", :_expand => "CustomFields"
SparkApi.client.post "/listings/#{listing_id}/contacts
```

I'm newer to Ruby, how would I use the GET/POST requests properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Install ruby
2. Run `gem install spark_api`
3. Create a SPARK_API_KEY and SPARK_API_SECRET

Then, you basically need to run a get and a post request.

This is the script from the documentation:

```
require 'spark_api'
SparkApi.configure do |config|
  config.endpoint   = 'https://sparkapi.com'
  # Using Spark API Authentication, refer to the Authentication documentation for OAuth2
  config.api_key    = 'SPARK_API_KEY'
  config.api_secret = 'SPARK_API_SECRET'
end

listing_id = 12345
filename = 'my_file.json'

def get_listing(listing_id, filename)
  response = SparkApi.client.get "/listings/#{listing_id}", :_expand => "CustomFields"
  save_to_file(response, filename)
end

def create_contact(listing_id)
  SparkApi.client.post "/listings/#{listing_id}/contacts"
end

def save_to_file(response, filename)
  File.open(filename, 'w') do |f|
    f << response.body
  end
end
```

Use your own HTTP client like [faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) or [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) but use the Gem which wraps all the API logic.

Comment: `Invalid API key and/or request signed improperly (SparkApi::PermissionDenied)` i added all the correct keys and stuff

Comment: Error code 1000 "Invalid API key and/or request signed improperly" is the message that shows that authentication failed. The question is if the API does not allow this auth method anymore or if your key / secret is wrong. Maybe it's worth looking into the other auth methods, e.g. oauth -> https://github.com/sparkapi/spark_api/blob/master/script/oauth2_example.rb

Comment: yo, appreciate all the help, just for answering and helping out, you got the bounty. Congrats.